# Textmate bookmark behavior on emacs

Tags: emacs, textmate, bookmarks

Is there a way to have the same behavior as Textmate's bookmark functions in emacs?

In Textmate, after I bookmark a line (with an F key - no need to name it), I can return to it with another F key (again, without the need to name the bookmark).

Beside that, I can have several unamed bookmarks on a page, and cicle through them just pressind the "go-to bookmark" F Key.

Let's break the question:

- It's possible to bookmark lines on a file without the need to name them and without the need to press RET?
- It's possible to have several unamed bookmarks on a single file?
- It's possible to cicle between them, also without the need to press RET?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

- It's possible to bookmark lines on a file without the need to name them and without the need to press RET?
- It's possible to have several unamed bookmarks on a single file?
- It's possible to cicle between them, also without the need to press RET?

Yes, yes, and yes.  And much more --- using [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus).

For the first two questions, see the doc section about [*autonamed* bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#toc55). For the third question, see the section about [*cycling*](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#toc50) among a set of bookmarks (e.g., the autonamed bookmarks in the current buffer).

Answer (score 0):

I would say "position registers" is the emacs way.
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Position-Registers.html#Position-Registers

A simpler alternative would be to use the mark, although it's a different way to save and jump positions, since they have no associated name/key:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark.html

Comment: Actually, I think the behaviour described in [The Mark Ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark-Ring.html#Mark-Ring) sounds almost exactly like what's asked for. `C-SPC` `C-SPC` creates unnamed bookmarks, and `C-u` `C-SPC` cycles through them. (The only problem is that you will set the mark more often than you might want to set a bookmark.)